# importing unity 2Dgame kit shows some errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 2018.3.0f2

I was studying unity [2D Game Kit Walkthrough](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/2d-game-kit-walkthrough)

it needs [2D Game Kit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/2d-game-kit-107098).

I downloaded it through unity app and then started it. After a long time and many loading and processing finally unity project opened. but show me some errors:

```
An error occurred while resolving packages:
  Project has invalid dependencies:
    com.unity.package-manager-ui: Package [com.unity.package-manager-ui@2.1.2] cannot be found
  Package com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0 has invalid dependencies:
    com.unity.ugui: Package [com.unity.ugui@1.0.0] cannot be found
```

---

```
Assembly has reference to non-existent assembly 'Unity.ugui' (Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro/Scripts/Editor/Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.asmdef)
```

I searched but didn't find any useful thing about solving problem.

can someone help me?

Comment: Its telling you it it needs different packages loaded from the package manager.

Comment: so should i download 3 packages? how? can you give me a useful link?

Comment: Well, 2018.3.0f2 is 5 months old, there have been many updates, 2019.1 is out now.. in which it loaded without issue.. so.. it tries to load in packages if it cant usually it has lost the internet connection.. but.. wouldnt know, cant see, but it tells you exactly whats wrong.

Comment: well, I installed version 2019.2.0a4 but I still have same problem !

Comment: Then id guess either your drive is full or your antivirus is playing up or something, as it worked fine for others.

Comment: @BugFinder problem solved thanks